# Ben Bova, science fiction giant, dead at 88

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Tor.com article](https://www.tor.com/2020/11/30/legendary-science-fiction-author-ben-bova-has-passed-at-the-age-of-88/comment-page-1/)

> Scientist, Hugo Award winner, and prolific science fiction author and editor Ben Bova passed away on Sunday, November 29, 2020 at the age of 88, Tor.com is able to confirm. The author of more than one hundred books, Bova also edited some of the genre’s best-known publications and served as the president of the Science Fiction and Fantasy Writers of America.
>
> Word of Bova’s passing first came from Kathryn Brusco, who revealed that Bova had passed due to complications from COVID-19 and a stroke.

Comment: https://twitter.com/orsonscottcard/status/1333786384805490688/photo/1

Answer (score 2):

Orion and the Exiles series were among the start of my science fiction habit.  He was such a compelling story-teller.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Bova was the editor of Analog who oversaw the original publication of Ender's Game.
Without him that entire series wouldn't have existed.